# How to convert varians of a character to the same character in python?

Tags: python, preprocessing, normalization

How to convert variants of a character to a same character in python.

For example, the character `a` with the `U+0061` Unicode has different variants like `U+1D5BA`, `U+1D5EE`, `U+1D622`, `U+1D656` ,`U+1D68A`. How to uniform a text by converting the variants to a same character? Is there any library to do that?

Actually I'm asking this question for a Non-English language. Is there any library which supports other languages?

I asked the question here, because It's a preprocessing problem and those who do data science could help me.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. This question is not specific to data science, it's about character encoding so SO would be a better place to ask (and you probably would get a better answer). SO even has a [`unicode` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unicode), your question is probably related to normalization like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-normalize-in-a-python-unicode-string), maybe it can help.

Comment: How do you import data? You can choose specific encodings which (often) lead to a correct way of displaying characters.